# No me realiza el descuento con else if en php

Tags: php

Primero que todo, me presento, soy Giovanni, nuevo en el grupo y este es mi primer post.
Ojala me explique bien para ser la primera vez...

estoy intentando realizar un descuento, llamado **private static $dcto_vehiculo;** , el cual se aplica sólo si el cliente compra un vehículo "Sedan" o "berlina", lo incluí cómo **else if**.

Mi problema es que no se aplica el descuento en el **$valor_final;**, al momento de elegir un Sedan o Berlina.

Muchas gracias. Dejo el código:
Muchas gracias. Dejo el código:
Muchas gracias. Dejo el código:Muchas gracias. Dejo el código:

```
<?php class Compra_vehiculo{
    
    private $precio_base;
    
    private static $ayuda=0;

    private $descuento_personal=25; // 25 % porciento

    private static $dcto_vehiculo; //descuento que no se aplica
    
            
    function Compra_vehiculo($gama){
        
        if($gama=="compacto"){
            
            
                $this->precio_base=20000;   
            
        }
        
        else if($gama=="berlina"){
            
                $this->precio_base=30000;   
            
        }

        else if($gama=="Sedan"){

                $this->precio_base=40000;

        }

        else if ($gama=="Sedan" or $gama=="berlina"){


            $this->dcto_vehiculo=($this->descuento_personal/100)*$this->precio_base;

        }           
        
        
    }// fin constructor

    
    static function descuento_gobierno (){

        if (date("m-d-y")>"10-13-20"){


        self::$ayuda=4500;

       }

    }
        
    function tapiceria_cuero($color){
        
        if($color=="blanco"){
        
            $this->precio_base+=3000;
        }
        
        else if($color=="beige"){
            
            $this->precio_base+=3500;
            
        }
        
        else{
            
            $this->precio_base+=5000;
            
        }
        
    }// fin tapicería
    
    
    
    function precio_final(){
        
        $valor_final=$this->precio_base-self::$ayuda-self::$dcto_vehiculo;
        
        return $valor_final;    
        
    }// fin precio final
            
    
}// fin clase
```

Answer (score 0):

tu error se da porque esta dentro de un `else if ($gama=="Sedan" or $gama=="berlina"){` es decir se evalúan todas las condiciones

si no es la primera salta a la segunda y así sucesivamente en tu caso la segunda y la tercera opción condicen con tu condición ya no tiene porque continuar....

hay varias formas para solventar esto.. una seria:

```
    <?php class Compra_vehiculo{
        
        private $precio_base;
        
        private static $ayuda=0;
    
        private $descuento_personal=25; // 25 % porciento
    
        private static $dcto_vehiculo; //descuento que no se aplica
        
                
        function Compra_vehiculo($gama){
            // empienzan las condiciones
            if($gama=="compacto"){
                    $this->precio_base=20000;   
            }
            
            // ambos se le agrega el codigo
            else if($gama=="berlina"){
                    $this->precio_base=30000;
                    $this->dcto_vehiculo=($this->descuento_personal/100)*$this->precio_base;  
                
            }
              // ambos se le agrega el codigo
            else if($gama=="Sedan"){
                    $this->precio_base=40000;
                    $this->dcto_vehiculo=($this->descuento_personal/100)*$this->precio_base;
    
            }        
            
            
        }// fin constructor
    
        
        static function descuento_gobierno (){
    
            if (date("m-d-y")>"10-13-20");
    
            self::$ayuda=4500;
    
           }
    
        }
            
        function tapiceria_cuero($color){
            
            if($color=="blanco"){
            
                $this->precio_base+=3000;
            }
            
            else if($color=="beige"){
                
                $this->precio_base+=3500;
                
            }
            
            else{
                
                $this->precio_base+=5000;
                
            }
            
        }// fin tapicería
        
        
        
        function precio_final(){
            
            $valor_final=$this->precio_base-self::$ayuda-self::$dcto_vehiculo;
            
            return $valor_final;    
            
        }// fin precio final
                
        
    }// fin clase
```

peque;a mejora en el caso de que quieres agregar o validar muchos mas vehiculos:

```
<?php class Compra_vehiculo{
    
    private $precio_base;
    
    private static $ayuda=0;

    private $descuento_personal=25; // 25 % porciento

    private static $dcto_vehiculo=0; //descuento que no se aplica
    
    private static $gama = ["compacto"=>20000,"berlina"=>30000,"Sedan"=>40000];

    private static $vehiculos_descuento =["berlina","Sedan"];
 function Compra_vehiculo($gama){

        // recorre el arreglo
        foreach ($this->gama as $key => $value) {
            // valida si el key o llave ["compacto","berlina","Sedan"] es igual a gama
            if($key==$gama){
                // obtiene el value [20000,30000,40000]
               $this->precio_base=$value;
               //valida que en los vehiculos con descuento exista ["berlina","Sedan"]
               if(in_array($key, $this->vehiculos_descuento)){
                 $this->dcto_vehiculo=($this->descuento_personal/100)*$this->precio_base;  
               }
               // sale una ves lo encuentre, para evitar seguir innecesariamente!
               break;
            }
        }
  
        
    }// fin constructor
```

también puedes mejorar la funcionalidad de las otras funciones pero eso ya es a gusto!

## saludos!

Comment: Un genio amigo. muchas gracias. por tu ayuda.!!!